# Initializing the memory using realloc()

Tags: c, memory, realloc

The question about `realloc()`.

If I want to size up the memory I allocated before with `realloc()`.

Will the additional memory be initialized to 0 just like `calloc()` or not?

The second question is:

```
    int * p =(int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    int* s = (int*)realloc(p,20);
    p=s;
```

Is assigning `s` to `p` a good way to resize the pointer `p`?

And can we `realloc()` the memory allocated with `calloc()`?

Comment: What did the manual say?

Comment: Except [the casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/) and lack of error checking, that looks almost like it should look. And no, the extra memory won't be initialized. You might want to check e.g. [this `realloc` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)

Comment: Oh, and your reallocation actually allocate *shrink* the allocated memory. The size you pass to `realloc` is the ***new*** size (in bytes) to allocate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the additional memory be initialized to 0?

No.

> can we `realloc()` the memory allocated with `calloc()`?

Yes.

> Is assigning `s` to `p` a good way to resize the pointer `p`

Depends.

Just doing

```
int * p = malloc(...);
int * s = realloc(p, ...);
p = s;
```

is the same as

```
int * p = malloc(...);
p = realloc(p, ...);
int * s = p;
```

In both cases, if [`realloc()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5) fails (and with this returned `NULL`) the address of the original memory is lost.

But doing

```
int * p = malloc(...);

{
  int * s = realloc(p, ...); /* Could use a void* here as well. */
  if (NULL == s)
  {
     /* handle error */
  }
  else
  {
    p = s;
  }
}
```

is robust against failures of [`realloc()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5). Even in case of failure the original memory is still accessible via `p`.

Please note that if [`realloc()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5) *succeeded* the value of the pointer passed in not necessarily addresses any valid memory any more. Do *not* read it, nor read the pointer value itself, as doing this in both cases could invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @xing:  Why? We have no context. So code as it stands is correct.

Comment: because in the context, I want to resize p from 10*sizeof(int) to 20*sizeof(int).

Comment: @Liu: Your question does not mention this.

Comment: anyway  it doesn't matter.

Comment: I don't understand the first and the last brackets.  And if realloc() failed, may I read the pointer I passed to it???

Comment: @Liu: Curly braces can be used to create a scope. This can be done to limit the validity of temporarily used variables for example `s` here. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: You mean if int * s = realloc(p, ...); succeeded, don't read what p points to or p itself??
But after we state p=s; after it succeeded, can we read what p points to or p itself??

Comment: @Liu: 1.) don't read neither p nor where it points to 2.) yes, you can read both

Comment: The reason why we can't read p or what p points to in the first case is because pointer p maybe relocated in memory if the following space wasn't large enough to accommodate the memory we add to p??

Comment: @liu: Probably, there might be other reasons as well.

Comment: @Liu: BTW, mind your wording: Nor is p reallocated nor is memory added to a pointer. Those things are done to memory the pointer points to and not to the pointer itself.